# C++ Common Ancestor Problem. What is it?

Tags: c++, inheritance

Hi I just finished taking my final exam. There was a questions that said, "define the common ancestor problem in C++", and state what feature of the language is used to address this problem.

I don't remember ever learning about the common ancestor problem in class or ever hearing about it. However I wrote the following:

I said it had to do with inheritance. If a parent class and a child class define the same method with the same method signature. So for instance if I have class Parent and class Child.

In class Parent I have

```
void sayHello(){
    cout << "hello I'm a parent" <<endl;
}
```

then in class Child I have

```
void sayHello(){
    cout << "hello I'm a child" <<<endl;
}
```

then if I have

```
Parent* p1;
Child* c1 = new Child();
p1 = & c1;
```

If I call `p1.sayHello()` I will call the `method sayHello()` from the parent class even though it's bounded to an instance of Child type.

So to address this we must use the virtual keyword and say

```
virtual void sayHeyllo(){
.....
}
```

so that wen I call p1.sayHello() it calls the method from the Child class and not the parent class.

Is this correct? I just took a guess, but it kind of makes sense. I googled C++ common ancestor problem, but nothing came up.  do you know if I'm right?

Thanks.
T

Comment: According my Googling, the Common Ancestor Problem is also known as the "Dreaded Diamond Inheritance".  This is where `virtual` inheritance comes in.

Answer (score 4):

I think they meant an inheritance diamond. When you have something like the following:

```
struct A {};
struct B : A {};
struct C : A {};

struct D : B, C {}; // here is the problem
```

The problem in `D` is there are two copies of `A` one comes from `B` and one from `C`. To solve this problem you have to use `virtual inheritance`:

```
struct A {};
struct B : virtual A {};
struct C : virtual A {};

struct D : B, C {}; // No problem!
```

Answer (score 4):

Probably it refers to a multiple inheritance where several base classes have a common parent ("[diamond inheritance](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/multiple-inheritance.html#faq-25.8)"):

```
struct A {};
struct B1 : A {};
struct B2 : A {};
struct C : B1, B2 {};
```

The solution asked for should be virtual inheritance:

```
struct A {};
struct B1 : virtual A {};
struct B2 : virtual A {};
struct C : B1, B2 {};
```

Answer (score 3):

This actually, normally, refers to the [Diamond Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem) with multiple inheritance.

Here is some [detailed reference material on how C++ treats this](http://cs.stmarys.ca/~porter/csc/common_341_342/notes/oop_multiple_inheritance.html).

Answer (score 3):

I would have thought that it is referring to Diamond inheritance (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem)

The C++ feature that you would use to deal with this is virtual inheritance:

```
class Foo : virtual public Bar
{
}
```

Search SO for diamond inheritance.